# How To Tell If User Is Signed Into Site From Socket.io Event

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am using express session to log users into my site. When they are logged in I can access their req.user which contains info about the user such as username, account age, ect.

The problem is that I need to be able to check if the user is signed in, inside of a socket.io event handler

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log(socket.request.session.id);
   io.sockets.on('message', function (socket) {
       //check if user is logged on here and if so broadcast the message to sockets
   })
});
```

As you can see I would need to be able to access req.user which I can't because it's inside a socket.io event handler, is there any other way I can tell if the user is logged in?

Comment: where is your message event emitted from?

Comment: A chat.js script on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...to be honest I'm still not 100% clear what you are doing, but instead of using the user you can also look at directly using the sockets (since you don't seem to need other user data aside from their login status):

1) You are trying to send a message from a connected socket to all other connected sockets (i.e. from a logged in user to other logged in users)

In this case, you will probably be instantiating a socket somewhere in your client-side javascript, such that each new client will open a new socket.

So, to ensure that all sockets available are for logged in clients, you can place the code for opening a new socket inside your login function, and simply use the server to `broadcast` to all connected sockets except the sender:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.request.session.id);
    io.sockets.on('message', function (data) {
        //check if user is logged on here and if so broadcast the message to sockets
      socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    })
```

});

2) You are trying to send a message from one socket to another connected socket (i.e. from one user to another specific logged in user)

Similarly, have your socket opened only during/after the login process.

Then, on your client side, you can do something like:

`socket.emit('message', "target_id");`

so that on the server side you can do:

```
socket.on("message", function(id) {
       socket.to(id).emit("message");
}
```

Does this help in any way?

Comment: I don't think I explained my question clearly. I have the user information inside req.user, and I have been using that to tell if the user is logged on or not. I need to check if the user is signed on inside the socket.io connection event.

Comment: which user? I was assuming that the code snippet you showed in your original question is in something like `server.js`, which will serve all connected users...

Comment: Yes it does, however I am using a module that allows users to sign into the site via their account on a gaming platform called steam. Once they sign in it gets saved to req.user and req.session.steamuser.

Comment: I actually have another question with more code, I made two because I didn't think anyone could understand this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960970/how-to-tell-if-user-is-logged-into-site-from-socket-io-event

Comment: I looked at your other post, and it is exactly the same as this one...but with more information, which makes it superior to this question. please avoid creating such duplicate questions next time, unless you are asking for different things in each question...

Comment: Ok sorry, but do you think you can still help me, I have been stuck on this for days.